# How do I validate Array and string in same params through rails params gem validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have use Rails params gem for rails params validation

```
        param! :answers, Array, blank: false, required: true do |x|
          x.param! :value, String, blank: false, reqiured: true, message: 'Value Can\'t Blank'
        end
```

value is both

```
params = "some random string" or params = ["some random string", "some random string", "some random string"]
```

In that params, value key was accept both string and array, I don't how to handle it

Answer (score 1):

I did not found anything like `or` or a support of multiple types.

Maybe you can use [`transform`](https://github.com/nicolasblanco/rails_param/tree/bc2cb3cfde704cab647e33bffa5b2a89827b0889#defaults-and-transformations) to cast your string to an array (code is not tested):

```rb
x.param! :value, Array, blank: false, reqiured: true, transform: lambda { |val| [val].flatten.reject(&:blank?) }, message: 'Value Can\'t Blank'
```

Comment: Can you upvote and mark my answer as a solution to your problem? :)

Comment: Sir i am also try to upvote my question and answer, but I can't sir, because it says
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.
```

Comment: You can avoid `flatten` by changing this to `[*val].reject(&:blank?)`